# Lookup Rows Error in email Preview and Test

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, lookup

I am trying to do a LookupRows call to print all the values in a row on a data extension, based on the “TriggeredSendCustomerKey” value and print the results in an email. I have the following code  but keep getting an error message when trying to preview and test the send.

```
%%[
 var @data
 set @data = LookupRows("MyAccount_Reporting", 1, "TriggeredSendCustomerKey", "")
 if RowCount(@data) > 0 then
  for @i = 1 to RowCount(@data) do
   var @content
   set @content = Field(Row(@data, 
  next @i
 endif
]%%

%%=v(@data)=%%
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share the error message?

Comment: You are missing the end part of your field and row functions when setting the content var.

Answer (score 0):

You have a code error:

```
set @content = Field(Row(@data,
```

This should be something like this:

```
set @content = Field(Row(@data,@i),"--YOUR COLUMN NAME IN DE--")
```

However, your LookupRows also looks odd:

```
 set @data = LookupRows("MyAccount_Reporting", 1, "TriggeredSendCustomerKey", "")
```

The second parameter should

> Name of the column that identifies the rows to retrieve

Please have a look here: https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/

**Update after comment:**
You should start reading a basic guide about AMPScript.

This output is set by you:

> System.Data.DataRow[]

```
%%=v(@data)=%%
```

**%%**: tells the interpreter that an AMPscript code is following

**=**: Short form for Output()

**v**: function to evaluate a variable

**@data**: the variable you have set

The variable **@data** is set here:

> set @data = LookupRows

The output is as expected a RowSet as described by the method LookupRows:

> This function returns a set of unordered rows from a Data Extension.

If you want to output the value of each row, you need to output content inside the foreach. This is shown in the example link I have shared.

The following code will do:

```
%%[ 
    var @data 
    set @data = LookupRows("MyAccount_Reporting","TriggeredSendCustomerKey","") 

    if RowCount(@data) > 0 then 
        for @i = 1 to RowCount(@data) do 
            var @content 
            set @content = Field(Row(@data,@i),"TriggeredSendCustomerKey") 
            Output(v(@content))
        next @i 
    endif 
]%%
```

Comment: Thanks all, I updated the code and dont get an error but get : "System.Data.DataRow[]" as a result..

Comment: updated code:  ```%%[
 var @data
 set @data = LookupRows("MyAccount_Reporting","TriggeredSendCustomerKey","")
 if RowCount(@data) > 0 then 
  for @i = 1 to RowCount(@data) do
   var @content
set @content = Field(Row(@data,@i),"TriggeredSendCustomerKey")
  next @i
 endif
]%% ```

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Got this working, thanks all!